How to make a REST call through terraform to a private Azure resource?
I do not this this question needs to be Azure resource-specific, but I will provide my background. I currently have Terraform code that creates an Azure AI Search service, disables public network access, and connects it to a private endpoint. This private endpoint is connected to the same virtual network and subnet as a CosmosDB Mongo resource, which holds the data I want to index from.
There is not a way to create indexes/indexers/datasources in Terraform through the hashicorp/azurerm/azurerm_search_service, so I am using mastercard/restapi to do so. I am following this guide as well: https://medium.com/expert-thinking/mastering-azure-search-with-terraform-a-how-to-guide-7edc3a6b1ee3
I'm starting by creating a datasource to connect the Azure Search and CosmosDB resources.
providers.tf
provider "restapi" {
  uri                   = "https://example-search.search.windows.net"
  write_returns_object  = true
  debug                 = true

  headers = {
    "api-key"       = module.az-search.azure_search_api_key
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
  }

  create_method   = "POST"
  update_method   = "PUT"
  destroy_method  = "DELETE"
}

az-search/main.tf
...
# Create the Datasource for the Product Collection in DB
resource "restapi_object" "create_product_datasource" {
  path          = "/datasources"
  query_string  = "api-version=2024-05-01-Preview"
  data          =  jsonencode(local.product_datasource_json)
  id_attribute  = "name"
}

locals {
  product_datasource_json = {
    description = "Links Azure Search with the Product Collection within CosmosDB"
    type        = "cosmosdb"
    subtype     = "MongoDb"
    credentials = {
      connectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://${azurerm_search_service.search.name}.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=${var.cosmosdb_readonly_key};Database=DB;ApiKind=MongoDB"
    }
    container = {
      name = "Product"
      query = null
    }
    name    = "product-datasource"
    identity = null
  }
}

The above code will create a datasource correctly when the Azure AI Search and CosmosDB resources are publicly accessible, however, I am not sure how to create this restapi_object when both of the resources are private. Both of the resources are within the same vnet and subnet and have a private endpoint.
Here is the error I get when applying:
│ Error: Post "example-search/datasources?api-version=2024-05-01-Preview": unsupported protocol scheme ""
│
│   with module.main.module.az-search.restapi_object.create_product_datasource,
│   on ../../modules/az-search/main.tf line 52, in resource "restapi_object" "create_product_datasource":
│   52: resource "restapi_object" "create_product_datasource" {
|

I am also open to using a different provider other than mastercard/restapi if needed, though the guide was very helpful since I am not familiar with it. Let me know if any more tf files are needed to answer this question.


Making a REST call through terraform to a private Azure resource

As per the Github Issues the blocker you're facing unsupported protocol scheme  the uri parameter in provider restapi is not matching with the requirement.
In the documentation you mentioned the uri parameters was utilized directly from the search service where are in this configuration, we will achieve the same from dns record.
Here I was created every resource from the terraform configuration where both the resources are connected to same vnet and subnets. How ever I will be sharing the code from the rest api provider as the blocker youre facing was from this instant.
My terraform configuration:
provider "restapi" {
  uri                   = "https://${azurerm_private_dns_a_record.search_dns_record.name}.search.windows.net"
  write_returns_object  = true
  debug                 = true

  headers = {
    "api-key"       = var.azure_search_api_key  # Use the variable
    "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
  }

  create_method   = "POST"
  update_method   = "PUT"
  destroy_method  = "DELETE"
}

resource "restapi_object" "create_product_datasource" {
  path          = "/datasources"
  query_string  = "api-version=2024-05-01-Preview"
  data          = jsonencode(local.product_datasource_json)
  id_attribute  = "name"
}

locals {
  product_datasource_json = {
    description = "Links Azure Search with the Product Collection within CosmosDB"
    type        = "cosmosdb"
    subtype     = "MongoDb"
    credentials = {
      connectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://${azurerm_private_dns_a_record.cosmosdb_dns_record.name}.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=${var.cosmosdb_readonly_key};Database=DB;ApiKind=MongoDB"
    }
    container = {
      name = "Product"
      query = null
    }
    name    = "product-datasource"
    identity = null
  }
}

here the primary read only keys are fetched from the search service and cosmos DB as per the requirement.
Terraform apply:



reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview

@ban_ana Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

sorry, I am unable to check this solution as I don't have access to the private DNS A record for my CosmosDB service. It's created and managed by another team. I was attempting to find a way around this, though unfortunately could not.

With the above code I am getting a different error:  Post "https://EXAMPLE.search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2024-05-01-Preview": dial tcp: lookup EXAMPLE.search.windows.net on ---: no such host
